# Performance optimization techniques for React Native apps?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, performance, optimization

I've been working on a React Native app and **I'm looking for some tips and techniques to optimize its performance**. While the app works fine, I've noticed some sluggishness and occasional lags during heavy usage or on lower-end devices.

I would appreciate any suggestions or best practices for improving the performance of React Native apps. Are there any specific techniques, libraries, or tools that can help with performance optimization? Any insights into reducing rendering times, optimizing memory usage, or improving overall responsiveness would be highly valuable.

I'm already using techniques like code splitting, lazy loading, and memoization, but I'd love to hear about any other strategies that have proven effective in your experience.
Thank you in advance for your suggestions!

Answer (score 1):

These are some tips that I used for my own app:

1- First avoid using inline functions, for example, I  used to use `Native Stack Navigator` like this

```js
  <Stack.Screen
    name="AVRoot"
    component={props => <AVRoot {...props} />}
  />
```

changing it to this improved my app performance

```js
  <Stack.Screen name="AVRoot">
    {props => <AVRoot {...props} />}
  </Stack.Screen>
```

2- Second use `React.memo` for functional or `React.PureComponent` for class components as much as you can.

3- Third use `react-native-fast-image` package for rendering your images. it will cache the image data so you can load them better.

4- Using hooks in functional components results in cleaner and faster mobile app. I believe even migrating from class component to functional had effects on my app performance.

5- reduce using states, and instead use references **if possible**.

```js
const [isOpen, setIsopen] = useState<boolean>(false);

const func = useCallback(() => {
  if(isOpen.current)
    console.log("sth")
  else setIsopen(false);
}, [isOpen])
```

instead:

```js
const isOpen = useRef<boolean>(false);

const func = useCallback(() => {
  if(isOpen.current)
    console.log("sth")
  else isOpen.current = false;
}, [isOpen.current])
```

6- Use `Flatlist` instead of rendering the list of data inside a `ScrollView`